# disable screenshots in phantomjs

Tags: automation, phantomjs, geb, headless-browser

How do I stop phantomjs from taking screenshots? I need to run a test in parrallel a bunch of times using jmeter. JMeter randomly fails on some of the tests and I'm suspecting it could be Phantomjs trying to save a screenshot of the test run. With multiple threads trying to write a file to the same place at the same time I'm assuming this may be an issue. If not I'd still like to try disabling the ability to save a screenshot.

I had needed to disable phantomjs from logging and had gotten it to work with the following code:

```
headlessNoLogs {
    driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
        ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
        cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver-loglevel=NONE");
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
        Logger.getLogger(PhantomJSDriverService.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
        new PhantomJSDriver(caps)
    }
}
```

Disabling the logging is working as expected. But I'm setting `takesScreenshot, false` and phantomjs is still taking screenshots.

Comment: tried several ways as many examples using this property (as your case) and tried also to set the properties with a CLI param --config but can't run phantomJs through geb without taking sreenshots neither...